# Reason for sending numbers from 0 to $2^n − 1$ in Deutsch–Jozsa algorithm

Tags: quantum-algorithms, nielsen-and-chuang, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

In Nielsen and Chuang, when talking about the Deutsch–Jozsa algorithm. The Deutsch’s problem is described as the following game.

> Alice, in Amsterdam, selects a number x from 0 to $2^n − 1$, and mails it in a letter to Bob, in Boston...

Is there an underlying reason why we use numbers from 0 to $2^n − 1$ or it's just a random choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers from $0$ to $2^n-1$ are exactly what one can encode into $n$ bits or $n$ qubits using standard binary [positional number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation). The mapping looks like this

$$
\begin{align}
&0\dots000 \mapsto 0 \\
&0\dots001 \mapsto 1 \\
&0\dots010 \mapsto 2 \\
&0\dots011 \mapsto 3 \\
&0\dots100 \mapsto 4 \\
&0\dots101 \mapsto 5 \\
&\ \ \dots \\
&1\dots111 \mapsto 2^n-1.
\end{align}
$$

In other words, it follows the same pattern as the well-known decimal notation only using two symbols instead of ten. Note that $n$ decimal positions correspond to numbers from $0$ to $10^n-1$.